# abbreviation or not Drive vs. dr home address

Tags: differences, synonyms, abbreviations

I put my home address on a credit application:

> 266 Chateau La Salle Drive

credit report has

> 266 Chateau La Salle dr

Is there a reference source to acceptability?

Comment: I see no issue if it has been abbreviated to *Capital* Dr.   lowercase dr is cause for complaint.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but this is not really a question about English at all, just about address formatting conventions that depend on locale rather than language.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the US (which is not a good assumption, but I'm sure there are analogous services in every developed country), you can go to the [US Postal Service website](https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress) to get the approved address format for your location, including abbreviation for road types.  Also, specifically for street suffixes, you can check [this handy-dandy chart](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm).